# Issue in generation of war or ear file

Tags: java, weblogic, netbeans-7

I have a project which is imported into NetBeans and I'm trying to generate a WAR file or EAR file which is used for deployment into web logic server.
When I clean and build, it is automatically generating a JAR file.

The project is imported from a zip file which includes web services and Java files.  After importing how do I generate a WAR or EAR file?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a web project to generate war file